# sublime video player source

Tags: video, ruby-on-rails-3.2, html5-video

I am programming with ruby on rails.

If I post a Video on a static page of my App it works:

```
<video controls
  src="video001.mp4"
  width="580" height="360"
  poster="default.png"
  id="video">
</video>
```

Both, the video itself AND the poster (picture) are saved in the "/public" directory.

BUT I have an Issue when I put the exact same lines of code for the Video-Tag into a "users/show.html.erb" page. To me it seems the Browser does not know where to get the Video AND Picture from. There is no error message shown, just an transparent HTML5-Player and I can not click anything. Can somebody please tell me how to solve this Issue. Or what is the best way to define a correct source (EVEN) at rendered pages such as "users/show". I have really tried every possible path that came to my mind.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who rated this down, shoulda better WRITE what's wrong with the post, so ONE CAN IMPROVE. No offense here, but wild-thumbing-down don't help anyone.